# How to COMPLETLEY remove wine

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, wine

I was using wine while after a while tried to use an exe and outputted `wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\"AN APP.exe"` This is the only exe that did that, now I know it's because I need to use 32 bit version of wine, so I want to uninstall wine and install it as a debian package file instead of a tarball, deleted the .wine folder, tarball, everything and it didn't work. I already viewed tons of problems, and all the commands they suggest doesn't work, any help?

I use kubuntu 18.04 by the way.

Answer (score 3):

There is no single answer: A tarball is not an organized *package* of software, but a bunch of files that happen to be transmitted together in a single-file *archive*. Those files are installed however the install instructions or script might dictate.

Look carefully at that tarball. Did it include uninstall instructions? Or an uninstall script? If not, you must figure out what it installed and where, and remove each file manually.

The pain of tarballs is why distros moved away from tarballs to organized software packages and package managers over 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The tarball can tell you the files that were unpacked with `tar tf mytarball.tar`, so you have a starting point. What any scripts created and left behind in system directories, however, if anyone's guess.

You can use QDirStat's "unpackaged files" view to inspect what files in system directories don't belong to any installed software package:

https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/Unpkg-View.md

(QDirStat 1.5 or later)